# interface class implements Runnable

Tags: java

there is a interface class, and an another class which implements this interface. If this interface had made as "extends Runnable", then there is a conflict in another class which implements this interface class. Why ? how may i implement the another class which implementing interface class ?

Comment: Can you post a working example. Currently what you are saying is confusing, and seems vague. An interface cannot implement another interface. What exactly do you have?

Comment: Is it an interface or a class?  "Interface class" is a bit wacky of a phrase to be using when you're talking about the specifics of such things.  :P

Comment: I think You need to elaborate your question.And what is `interface class` :D

Comment: @Learner, it is an ordinary interface, stored in a `.class` file ;)

Comment: @khachik hahahahaha It means I am still lacking :( in Java Interface Technology :D

Comment: @user1791618 we expect that you accept some answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, an interface can extend another interface, but an interface cannot implement another interface.
You can use something like this:

```
YourClass implements YourInterface, Runnable { ... }
```

Or an alternative could be this:

```
YourInterface extends Runnable { ... }
YourClass implements YourInterface { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

There won't be any ambiguity because all the methods in interface are abstract. And that's also the reason that a class is not allowed to extend more than one class in Java.